# Using ColorFill on a depth buffer

Tags: directx9

I'm trying to implement a render abstraction over Direct3D9, and one of the functions I'm implementing is clearing a render target, which includes a depth buffer. However, the `IDirect3DDevice9::ColorFill` method I've been using doesn't seem to be able to clear depth buffers. Is the only means to clear depth buffers to use `Clear()` to clear depth buffers which have been bound to the rendering pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear() is the only way.

To understand why, you need to consider that Direct3D is an abstraction layer itself over the underlying hardware to present a way for you to code against them all. If you dig a little deeper behind the scenes on depth in particular, you start to discover that each manufacturer is free to implement (and therefore optimise) depth as they choose, as long as they adhere to the interface presented.

The link [here](http://forum.beyond3d.com/archive/index.php/t-562.html) describes a little about some of the different techniques that have been used, it seems to date from 2002 so things will have advanced since then, but it gives you an idea of why they hide the underlying implementation from you. The Wikipedia link on HyperZ [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperZ) also talks a little about some of the optimisation methods used and the efficiencies they get from them.

Comment: Suddenly, I'm feeling rather glad that I don't have to implement these functions.